# vcgencmd is missing in arch linux

Tags: firmware

I have recently acquired a Raspberry Pi 3B+, and I have installed arch linux on it. So far, so good, but vcgencmd is missing, and I am not able to find a way to get it installed. Can somebody help me?

Comment: https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=12746 ?

Comment: yeah, thank you: I had already seen that, but in my installation nothing is to be found under /opt :-/

Comment: so `pacman -Q raspberrypi-firmware` shows it is installed?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to install `raspberrypi-firmware`, such as with

```
sudo pacman -S raspberrypi-firmware
```

Then restart shell. The program is installed to `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd`